# How to login with url and hash parameter only in Laravel? (without username and password)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, url, hash

I want to send users link with their own hashes to login without inputing form, I already tried it but it's too slow so I'm not sure if it even works:

web.php

```
Route::get('link/{hash}', 'Auth\LoginController@loginless')->where('hash', '(.*)');
```

LoginController.php

```
public function loginless($hash)
{
    $response           = array();
    $response['status'] = 500;
    $response['url']    = null;
    
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $arr_username = User::select('username','password')->get();
    
    foreach ($arr_username as $arr){
        if (Hash::check($arr->username, $hash)){
            $username = $arr->username;
            $password = $arr->password;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (\Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['url']    = route('dashboard');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Any way to make it more efficient? (is it possible without foreach?)

Comment: Hash::check is intended to take a long time to prevent passwords from being brute forced easily. You can't make it efficient _and_ secure. I'd recommend against giving the users their hash, and against making a link that can login a user via a GET request, as any app (like chat or email) might try to grab the page to render a preview. If you absolutely must do this, at least use an expiring one-time password via a POST request. (See how philo.com does it.)

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. Just a comment, this might help: https://blog.logrocket.com/magic-login-links-with-laravel/

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you can use encryption with key, [check this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypt-with-specific-key)